# How to disable screenshot option shortcut in Mojave CMD+Shift+5

Tags: screen-capture, mojave

Using Skitch, I now get duplicate screenshot options.

I want to disable the screenshot shortcut option in macOS Mojave.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Go to: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Screenshots

Uncheck: Screenshot and recording options

[image: Screenshots Keyboard Shortcuts]