# Unable to take screenshot in MacBook using shortcut shift+command+3/4

Tags: macos, screen-capture

On macOS I type the key combinations: shift+command+3/4

2. While taking the screenshot sound is audible but the screenshot is not getting saved in desktop or anywhere. I have searched in spotlight and in finder as well.
3. Also checked the shortcuts in keyboard option; all are checked.

How can I look at where the system stores the actual screen shot location and validate / reset that it's saving files to a writeable location?

Comment: what macOS - the check/fix depends on which.

Comment: I'm editing out "tried everything" unless you document a specific thing you tried, how do we know you searched for the one article that will explain how to troubleshoot this? Also Tetsujin is correct - we can't guess which OS you have - on Mojave - start here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340634/how-to-disable-screenshot-option-shortcut-in-mojave-cmdshift5

Answer (score 1):

If the default location for saving screenshots has been changed, then this Terminal command will show you the changed location:

```
defaults read com.apple.screencapture location
```

If you get a message that the *default pair does not exist*, then the location has not been changed, and should be the Desktop.

If you want to restore it to the default, enter:

```
defaults delete com.apple.screencapture location
```